# Get currently selected language of backend user in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

In a PHP function **in the Backend context**, I would like to determine the currently selected language of the BE user.

In my use case, the editor chooses from a list of values (generated by an [itemsProcFunc](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/CommonProperties/ItemsProcFunc.html#tca-property-itemsprocfunc)) in a [Flexform](http://Flexform). The values are localized.

**Example**:

This is the flexform output:

[image]

The labels which are displayed in the multi-select box are created dynamically in an itemsProcFunc and should be displayed in English, if the user's preferred language in the backend is English.

Comment: Usecase seems to be very special. Shouldn't content depend on the language of the *page*, not of the BE-User/BE-User's language-settings?

Comment: The question refers to backend context. Perhaps I should have mentioned that, but I did write Flexform. In my usecase, the flexform shows a list of values to choose from which are localized (English / German) - these are the same values that will also be shown in the FE as headers. But having the values shown in the user's language makes it easier for for the editor to choose in the list in the flexform. Because other resources I found always refer to the FE language, I thought it might be a good idea to open a question for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lang = $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->uc['lang'] ?? '';
if ($lang === '') {
    $lang = 'en';
}
```

- [Backend user settings](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/UserSettingsConfiguration/Index.html) can be retrieved, using the `uc` array in the backend user object.
- If the currently selected language is "en", an empty string is returned.

---

Note: Since TYPO3 9 [context and aspects](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html#user-aspect) should be used instead of querying global variables (e.g. `$GLOBALS['BE_USER']`), however I am not aware of a way to do this particular thing (get lang from preferences) without `$GLOBALS['BE_USER']`.